# Wpf c# how to close window in page?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I found the problem is It cannot close this window. But it can open the MainWindow.
pls help
[image]
Code in button

```
        private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow MainView = new MainWindow();
            MainView.Show();

            AuthWindow AuthView = new AuthWindow();
            AuthView.Close();

        }
```

I want to press the button inside the page and close that window and open another window.

Comment: `new AuthWindow()` creates a **new** AuthWindow which you then immediately close. Do you plan to close an existing window? Then you need a reference to it.

Comment: How? I'm new to this.

Comment: i want to close AuthWindow after that open MainWindow.

Comment: Is the method `LoginBtn_Click` in the `AuthWindow` class? If yes, just use `this.Close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such scenarios, I advise you to use RoutedCommand. In this case, you can use the ready-made command `ApplicationCommands.Close`.

In the page button, specify the command name:

```xml
    <Button Content="Close Window" Command="Close" />
```

In the Window, set command executing:

```xml
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Close" Executed="OnCloseWindow"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
    private void OnCloseWindow(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
```

**P.S.** I also do not advise you to open new windows. Since you are using Pages, you should change Pages in a single Window. And closing the Window is regarded as an Exit from the Application.